# $\lim_{n→∞} f(n+x)=0$ results in $ \lim_{x→∞} f(x)=0$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

$f\colon [0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ is uniformly continuous.

If $\lim_{n\to \infty}f(n+x)=0$ where $x\in [0,1]$, then $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)=0$.

every my trying to solve this is wrong :(

how can i prove this?

and if $f$ is just continuous, what happens to the results

Comment: Couldn't you let $x=0$ in the first part and produce the second result as $n+x=n+0=n$ or am I missing something here?

Comment: @JBKing My best guess is that the first limit is over integers $n$, and the second over real numbers $x$.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the function that is zero everywhere except at the intervals $[n-1/n,n]$, where its graph forms an isosceles triangle of height $1$ with base on the $X$-axis.

This function satisfies the hypothesis but $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n-1/2n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}1=1$.

Now, let $\epsilon>0$ be any positive real number. Then, there is $N>0$ such that if $|x-y|<1/N$ then $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$.

Take $M>0$ such that $|f(n+k/N)|<\epsilon$ for all $k=0,1,...,N-1$, and $n>M$.

Now assume $x>M$. Then $|f(x)|\leq|f([x])|+|f(x)-f([x])|$, where $[x]$ is the number of the form $n+k/N$ closest to $x$.

Finally

$|f([x])|+|f(x)-f([x])|<\epsilon+\epsilon$.

Comment: mr jack i have a question. Dose considering the function generalize this hypothesis? i mean if there is another fuction satisfied this hypothesis then can we guarantee this proof?