# Uniformly continuous function $f:[0, \infty)$ $\to$ $\mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity

I've got some inquiries while doing exercise. I want to share it and ask advices.

Here's the problem.

---

We have uniformly continuous function $f:[0, \infty)$ $\to$ $\mathbb R$ satisfies $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}$ $f(n+x)=0$ whenever $x \in [0, 1]$ and $n \in \mathbb N$.
Show that $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}$ $f(x)=0$. And if the uniformly continuous condition changes into continuous condition, the statement still holds?

---

In my trial, I approached with the $\epsilon$ - $\delta$ method and made some outcome but little bit unsatisfied. And I have difficulty in finding some easy counter-example of the if-question. I wonder there are any ideas better than $\epsilon$ -$\delta$ method and easy counter-examples.

### EDIT:

Here's the specification about the curiosity I have.

In this problem, the difference between limit through natural number and through real number matters. I think because of $\mathbb N$ $\subsetneq$ $\mathbb R$, limit through $\mathbb R$ implies limit through $\mathbb N$ but the converse doesn't. What I had to request was the logical explanation about this difference and background understanding of this theme. This situation is very common in analysis but I haven't seriously thought about it.

Comment: For a counterexample, think for example of a continuous nonnegative function that takes the value $1$ at every *multiple* of $\pi$ but takes the value $0$ just about everywhere else.

Comment: Sorry, I found a big typo and made a correction. Please read again.

Comment: Are we to think of $n \in \Bbb{Z}$ or $n \in \Bbb{R}$?

Comment: Added. $n \in \mathbb N$

Comment: @GregMartin But such a function is not continuous.

Comment: @Greg that sounds like you'd need to find a sequence $a_m$ such that $|x+\mathbb{Z}-\pi m|\in o(a_m) \forall x\in [0,1)$. Does that exist?

Comment: @pigeon that's why he said "just about" , I believe

Comment: I would have just taken a function that has bumps moving towards $\mathbb{Z}$ fwiw

Comment: @Bananach what does $|x+\mathbb{Z}-\pi m| \in o(a_m)$ mean?

Comment: Greg commented before I changed $f(nx)$ to $f(n+x)$. Sorry everyone.

Comment: @pigeon Minimal distance of set ($x+\mathbb{Z}$) to point ($\pi m$)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first part, we fix $\epsilon > 0$, and choose $\delta > 0$ so that $|x - y| < \delta \implies |f(x) - f(y)| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$. Let $N \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ so that $\frac{1}{N} < \delta$, and partition $[0,1]$ to $\left[0,\frac{1}{N}\right] \cup \left[\frac{1}{N},\frac{2}{N}\right] \cup \cdots \cup \left[\frac{N-1}{N},1\right]$. Since $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(n + x) = 0$ $\forall x \in [0,1]$, or each $\frac{k}{N}$, there exists an $M_k \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ large enough so that:
$$
x \in \left\{M_k + \frac{k}{N}, (M_k + 1) + \frac{k}{N}, \dots\right\} \implies |f(x)| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}
$$
We let $M = \max\{M_0,M_1,\dots,M_N\}$. Now for any $x > M$, we have $x \in \left(T + \frac{k}{N}, T + \frac{k+1}{N}\right)$ for some $T \in \mathbb{Z}^+, T \geq M$. Then:
$$
|f(x)| \leq \left|f(x) - f\left(T + \frac{k}{N}\right)\right| + \left|f\left(T + \frac{k}{N}\right)\right| < \frac{\epsilon}{2} + \frac{\epsilon}{2} = \epsilon
$$
Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, we have $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 0$.

This statement does not hold if we simply let $f$ be continuous. I'll adopt the counterexample posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/738292/lim-n%e2%86%92%e2%88%9e-fnx-0-results-in-lim-x%e2%86%92%e2%88%9e-fx-0?noredirect=1&lq=1):
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
2n\left(x - \left(n - \frac{1}{n}\right)\right), &\text{if $x \in \left[n - \frac{1}{n},n - \frac{1}{2n}\right]$ for some $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$} \\
-2n(x - n), &\text{if $x \in \left[n - \frac{1}{2n},n\right]$ for some $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$} \\
0, &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
As the OP of the original answer said, this function is zero everywhere except on all intervals in the form of $\left[n - \frac{1}{n}, n\right]$, where there is an isosceles triangle of height $1$ (so the "tip" of the triangle is on every $x = n - \frac{1}{2n}$).  Then for any $x \in [0, 1]$, we have $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(n + x) = 0$, as for sufficiently large $n$ we have $x < 1 - \frac{1}{n + 1}$, so $n + x < n + 1 - \frac{1}{n + 1}$. Visually, this means that the points $n + x$ lie strictly on the left of the isosceles triangles on intervals $\left[n - \frac{1}{n}, n\right]$, so $f(n + x)$ becomes $0$ eventually. However, it is not true that $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 0$, as if we take the sequence of points $x_n = n - \frac{1}{2n}$, we have $x_n \to \infty$ yet $f(x_n) = 1$ $\forall n$ (recall that $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 0$ iff for any sequence of points $(x_n)$ such that $x_n \to \infty$, we have $f(x_n) \to 0$).

---

**EDIT**: With regards to the added specification, your explanation is actually pretty good and reflects well on what is happening here in the problem. In order for $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 0$, we need to have $f(x_n) \to 0$ for **any** sequence $(x_n)$ such that $x_n \to \infty$. The information given, $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(n + x) = 0$ $\forall x \in [0, 1]$, only guarantees that $f(x_n) \to 0$ for **sequences $(x_n)$ which increases linearly** (i.e. $x_m - x_n \in \mathbb{Z}$ $\forall m,n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$). This does not tell us about the behaviour of $f$ for sequences which do not increase linearly. This explains why the counterexample works - the sequence $x_n = n - \frac{1}{2n}$ does not increase linearly anywhere.

However, the condition which $f$ is uniformly continuous tells us that we can approximate the behaviour of $f(x_n)$, where $x_n$ increases non-linearly, with linear sequences near it (by near, I mean $x \in \left(T + \frac{k}{N}, T + \frac{k+1}{N}\right)$). This allows us to ensure that the behaviour of $f(x)$ as $x \to \infty$ can be controlled entirely by linearly increasing sequences, which is why we can conclude $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 0$.

Comment: Thanks for the kind answer. The specification of the counter-example for if-question is helpful. But I already have this approach. Now I think my question isn't very specific enough to show my curiosities.

Comment: You can edit your question to explain what you're curious about, and I'll try to help.

Comment: Now I added some specification.

Comment: Okay, see my edited answer.

Comment: The speed of $x_n$ doesn't matter? In the counter-example, $x_n$ increases but under the linear speed. It doesn't matter since it does not follow $\mathbb N$ ?

Comment: $x_n$ does not increase linearly, as $x_{n+1} - x_n = 1 - \frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{1}{n} \notin \mathbb{Z}$. What do you mean by "speed"?

Comment: Now things are cleared up. I misunderstood that increasing speed of $x_n$ affect the convergence of $f(x_n)$ but whether following $\mathbb Z$ or not affect.